# Getting sub sites using rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

In alert I am getting [object object], I need to get names of all sub sites.

```
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetriveSites,"sp.js");

function RetriveSites()
{
$.ajax({
        url: "https://hp.sharepoint.com/teams/VeraxRep/_api/web/webs",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
alert(data.d.results);    // This gets alert of [object object]
 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var results = jsonObject.d.results;

    alert(results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Better to use Console.log instead of alert. Then in the console you can see the Json details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data.d.results` is an Array of object (Sub-Site). [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) can print message/string only in the right format.

If you need to see them as string, then use

```
JSON.stringify(data.d.results)
```

You do not need to use following code

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
var results = jsonObject.d.results;
```

Try some thing like following

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://hp.sharepoint.com/teams/VeraxRep/_api/web/webs?$select=Title,Url,ServerRelativeUrl",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var subSiteNames = [];
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
            subSiteNames.push(item.Title);
        });
        console.log(subSiteNames);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

`subSiteNames` is the Array that contains all sub-site's name. If you need them in a single string, the use

```
alert(subSiteNames.join(", "));
```

Based on the comment. You need the sub-site `URL`.

For Server Relative Url

```
item.ServerRelativeUrl
```

For absolute Url

```
item.Url
```

Comment: Thanks alot...what should I do to get the subsite names as links..

Comment: use `item.ServerRelativeUrl` instead of `item.Title`

Comment: This requires user to have Browse Directories permission. And in that case it returns all subwebs regardless of user permissions to that subweb. Must use  effectivebasepermissions filter as in answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Use the code given below, it will return the sub site name and url and save it in an arraylist named SubsiteDetails.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/webs/?$select=title,ServerRelativeUrl,Created,effectivebasepermissions&$filter=(effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032)&$orderby=Created desc",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var tempArray = data.d.results;
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
            var tempArray = new Array(2);
            tempArray[0] = item.Title;
            tempArray[1] = item.ServerRelativeUrl;
            SubsiteDetails.push(tempArray);
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/webs",
type: "GET",
headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Above code will return array of objects. Count of objects will be count of subSite. Each object will contain properties of each SubSite.